# OracleConnection throw null exception upon Open()

Tags: c#, oracle

When code reach .Open() method of OracleConnection object, it throw null exception, can't get why.
Here is code:

```
using (OracleConnection connection = new OracleConnection($"User Id={dbLogin};Password={dbPass};Persist Security Info=False;Data Source={server}"))
{
    connection.Open();
}
```

All info being passed to connection string correctly.
This sutiation happend when i'm trying to migrate from .Net oracle to ODA.NET, using Oracle.DataAccess v 4.0.3

Default System.Data.Oracle correctly opens the connection with that conenction string.
Read mostly all topics about migration, no luck so far.

Comment: Ehm, no? Im asking why Open mothod throw that exception, since it's correctly initialized.

Comment: @OwenPauling The words 'null reference' in a post doesn't automatically qualify it as a duplicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the problem was in the corrupted Oracle Client installation.

Weird part - there was just NullRef exception with no **ORA** errors.
After i've got proper install - everything works just fine.

Also reworked my code to *OracleDataAdapter* instead of *OracleDataReader* - code works faster and more stable.

Comment: I have found that with ODP.Net you don't always get good error reporting if you use a generic exception handler, if you catch an `OracleException` you get the ORA- number that will give you more information

Comment: Thanks mate!
But that part of my code can throw not only OracleException, and actually, i think that wasn't OracleProblem, just VS couldn't load dll's properly, or something like that.